# Error with indexWorker process in Sitecore 9 xConnect with Solr 6.6.2

Tags: solr, indexing, xconnect

I am running Sitecore 9 with Solr 6.6.2 and I am seeing lot of error in the IndexWorker logs in Sitecore xConnect as below:

```
018-02-21 16:16:13.686 +10:00 [Error] An error occured.
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 503 ({metadata={error-class=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException,root-error-class=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException},msg=SolrCore is loading,code=503}).
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrClient.<SendGetRequestAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrRebuildStatusStorage.<ReadStatus>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.IndexerHost.<RunRebuildStatusWatcher>d__28.MoveNext() in C:\BA\147b0adf6c2580c7\code\Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer\IndexerHost.cs:line 249
2018-02-21 16:16:13.687 +10:00 [Error] An error occured.
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 503 ({metadata={error-class=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException,root-error-class=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException},msg=SolrCore is loading,code=503}).
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrClient.<SendGetRequestAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrRebuildStatusStorage.<ReadStatus>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.IndexerHost.<RunRebuildStatusWatcher>d__28.MoveNext() in C:\BA\147b0adf6c2580c7\code\Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer\IndexerHost.cs:line 249
2018-02-21 16:16:13.704 +10:00 [Error] An error occured.
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 503 ({metadata={error-class=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException,root-error-class=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException},msg=SolrCore is loading,code=503}).
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrClient.<SendGetRequestAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrRebuildStatusStorage.<ReadStatus>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.IndexerHost.<RunRebuildStatusWatcher>d__28.MoveNext() in C:\BA\147b0adf6c2580c7\code\Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer\IndexerHost.cs:line 249
```

It is the bussqproject.xconnect-IndexWorker that is throwing this error, anyone come across similar issue?

Comment: If you stop the service and run it from command line do you get any errors. Do you check solr logs? Do you have many contacts and you increase java heap memory?

Comment: Did you check if the errors are all around specific times or it keeps failing? The indexer retries a bit aggressively by default, so you may get lots of entries in a short period of time (which could happen if Solr was restarted for example).

Comment: Yeah I haven't seen the error this morning in the logs. So might be a bit of glitch in Solr. Thanks for the help.